# How to center the label in MUI Textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to center the label and helper text in the middle of the Textfield. I got it working with adding a padding to MuiInputLabel-root. But this is not responsive on other screen sizes (Textfield changes size and the label isnt in the center anymore). I have tried using  `textAlign: 'center'`  but it doesnt work.

1. Currently I have the Textfield with label on the left: [Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JzmE.png)
2. I want to center the label and eventually helper Text too: [Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJy82.png)
3. Currently when focused paddingLeft is set to 0 again: [Focused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noaqR.png)

```html
const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)({
    '& .MuiInputLabel-root': {
        paddingLeft: '85px',
    },
    '& label.Mui-focused': {
        color: '#000000',
        paddingLeft: '0px',
    },
    
     <StyledTextField
                        helperText="Privacy Policy "
                        InputProps={{
                            inputProps: {
                                style: { textAlign: 'center' },
                            },
                        }}
                        margin="normal"
                        fullWidth
                        id="email"
                        label="Email Address"
                        name="email"
                        autoComplete="email"
                        autoFocus
                        sx={{
                            m: 1,
                        }}
                    />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I was able to solve your issue (updated code).

```
const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)({
  "& .MuiInputLabel-root": {
    right: 0,
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  "& .MuiInputLabel-shrink": {
    margin: "0 auto",
    position: "absolute",
    right: "0",
    left: "0",
    top: "-3px",
    width: "150px", // Need to give it a width so the positioning will work
    background: "white" // Add a white background as below we remove the legend that had the background so text is not meshing with the border
    // display: "none" //if you want to hide it completly
  },
  "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused": {
    "& legend ": {
      display: "none"
    }
  }
});

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  return (
    <StyledTextField
      helperText="Privacy Policy "
      InputProps={{
        inputProps: {
          style: { textAlign: "center" }
        }
      }}
      margin="normal"
      fullWidth
      id="email"
      label="Email Address"
      name="email"
      autoComplete="email"
      autoFocus
    />
  );
}
```

Here is the UPDATED [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-demo-material-ui-forked-jjh2gc?file=/demo.tsx:157-723) to try it. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Hey thanks, yeah I used the placeholder and removed the label as I am not able to center the label. You also do not need the "right: 0" to make it work with placeholder. Nevertheless I am even more curious now if its possible to center the label also when focused

Comment: You are right, the 'right:0' is needed if you want to use the label again. Just to clarify something, you want the label to be centered also when it shrinks on focus? or you don't want to be shown at all? Let me know and i will provide a solution. Thanks

Comment: @David I have updated the code and the codesandbox so you can use the label again, being centered and as the image 2 you have in your example. Please let me know if it worked, thanks

Comment: Yes it works thank you very much. Do you also know how to center the label when it shrinks on focus?

Comment: I have updated both the codesandbox and the answer with the label centered as you want now. I would appreciate the upvote and mark the answer as correct for future users. Thanks